# Proper way to setup oracle database for TCPS SSL in local machine

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, ssl, tcpip, setup

I am using oracle database 12c and would like to setup TCP SSL connection to be able to connect using the same machine where the database is hosted. So, connection would be from database machine to itself using SSL.

I believe there has to be some setup to the oracle wallet file but not quite sure what is the proper way to create the certificates since it will be on the same machines. Most tutorials show steps for a client to server setup, but I want a local setup.

Any help/guidance is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Comments should only be used for asking for clarification, or to leave constructive criticism that guides the author in improving the post, or to add relevant but minor or transient information to a post (e.g. a link to a related question, or an alert to the author that the question has been updated), or to provide site usage guidance.  See the [help](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) for details.

Answer (score 0):

The setup would be the same as for client-server. You still have a client and a server; they happen to be located on the same host, but you're still making a connection over the network.

Follow one of the tutorials you've already found, or consider this one: https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/configure-tcpip-with-ssl-and-tls-for-database-connections